# saveWorkbook Execution time

Tags: r, xlconnect

I'm sorry if this was already answered but I couldn't find.

I'm using the XLConnect package to add new entries to a spreadsheet, but the execution time of saveWorkbook is increasing and delaying all other tasks that depend on the updated spreadsheet.

The work flow is the following:

1. Query a SQL db for new entries (Load the result using read.table);
2. Load out-of-date spreadsheet and save each sheets as a entry of a
   list;
3. Add entries to appropriate sheets/list element;
4. Color lines, using setCellStyel, according to a series of
   parameters (example in code bellow);
5. saveWorkbook

```
cs_completo=getOrCreateCellStyle(wb, name = "Cs_Completo")
  setFillPattern(cs_completo, fill = XLC$FILL.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
  setFillForegroundColor(cs_completo, color = XLC$COLOR.LIGHT_GREEN)

for(status in c("Conferido","Impresso","Entregue","Envelopado")){
  if(sum(grepl(status,dados$NomeStatusExame))>0){
    index=which(grepl(status,dados$NomeStatusExame))+1
    lapply(1:length(desired_tabs),function(x) setCellStyle(wb, sheet = sheet,  row=index, col=x,cellstyle = cs_completo))}
  }
}
```

Steps 1 through 4 are complete under 3 three minutes (some sheets have as much as 2000 lines).

Step 5 takes at least 30 minutes!

Is there a way to speed up the saveWorkbook writing process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but saving the workbook to a new file take much less time (under a minute) than overwrite the existing one!